# mpiexec -np 8 ./wrf.exe consuming 100% of my cpu

Tags: cpu-usage, mpich, mpiexec

I am trying to run an executable (`wrf.exe`) using `mpiexec` under 8 cores. One problem I am encountering is that this process uses all the CPU on my computer and then crashes mid run. I tried to look for solutions for this problem on the internet including through the mpich literature and I have found nothing in regards to solving this problem.

Does anyone know how I can regulate the cpu usage when running `mpiexec -np 8 ./wrf.exe`?  I want it so I can allocate maybe 75% cpu usage to running this.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: that's expected, the wrf.exe _will_ use as much CPU as it can because that's his job, now if it crashes mid run though, that means something else, you can start looking at the rsl.error.XXXX files in the folder where you launched the mpirun, use the dmesg tool to see if the SO is killing the process or use the debug parameter in your namelist.input to get more verbosity on the log so you can troubleshoot the problem

Answer (score 0):

remove the -np 8, just mpiexec ./wrf.